# How many topologies can be defined on a finite set with $n$ element?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

we know that a topology on $A$ is a subset of the power set of $A$, with two properties;

$1)$ it is closed under finite intersection and arbitrary union.

$2)$ it must include $A$ and the empty set.

Now,if $A$ is a finite set with $n$ elements, how many topologies can be defined on $A$?

Or, how many topologies can be defined on $A$ up to a homeomorphism?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems nontrivial. Any papers I've found on the topic suggest that this is still an open problem. See the following [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements) on MathOverflow:

You might also see the following paper:

[The Number of Topologies on a Finite Set](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Benoumhani/benoumhani11.pdf)

Or this paper:

[Enumeration of Finite Topologies](http://cs.umaine.edu/~markov/Enumeration.pdf)

Comment: it seems to be an open problem,I wonder about second part of my question,what is that number up to homeomorphism? Of course ,I do not know whether this is more harder or easier? Or even if we can not compute both can we find the relation between these two number?thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine that your second question would be any easier because to know which would be homeomorphic one would think that you'd know what topologies there were to begin with. Of course in the finite case, finding homeomorphisms is a fairly simple matter regarding cardinality. But that still begs the question what topologies are there to begin with on a set of $n$ elements. So I believe your second question is as nontrivial as the first.

Comment: can we find the relation between them? I mean let $T(n)$ be number of the topology on a set with n element and $R(n)$ be number of the topology up to homeomorphism. even if we cant find $T(n)$ and $R(n)$ can we find $T(n)$ in terms of $R(n)$.

Comment: It's an open question, so I don't have an answer. I'd imagine there would have to be some kind of upper/lower bound.

Comment: The second question is much harder.  A friend and I did the 'raw' version as undergrads just out of curiosity.  Is the 'raw' version open?  ;D